# Trouble Finding Element by Xpath For Downloading A File Off Site w/Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, file, download

```
driver.get("https://www.scb.se/hitta-statistik/statistik-efter-amne/finansmarknad/finansmarknadsstatistik/finansmarknadsstatistik/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pageContent"]/div[1]/article/div/div[1]/p[1]/a').click()
```

I'm trying to figure out how to download file "Finansmarknadsstatistik, november 2021" under Tabeller och diagram from the site in driver.get with Python/Selenium, through xpath, but I am unfamiliar with HTML and the correct identifiers to obtain the file and save it to my directory.

I don't know what div[1] etc.. is and I need some help with identifying how to obtain the file.

All advice is appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (min-reprex)**, and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [**How to write a perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Where did you get the xpath you're using in the code?

Comment: If the file has an `<a>` link, then can't you just use the direct url?  Why are you using xpath at all?

Comment: The xpath was an example from a site I took off of trying to learn about HTML.  But I'm still confused.

Comment: A random xpath you found on some tutorial certainly won't work for your specific file.

Comment: @JohnGordon The problem is the file download link changes every new release so from November it will go to December, which will ruin the automation, so I need to make sure it simply obtains that file no matter what to keep up with the new release to the data.

Comment: @JohnGordon "A random xpath you found on some tutorial certainly won't work for your specific file" I know this but still gave something a shot lol

Comment: @JohnGordon Am I close to something here?  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@id='_Tabellerochdiagram']/following-sibling::a").click()

Comment: (//h2[@id='_Tabellerochdiagram']/following-sibling::ul//a)[1] did you always want the first a tag or the one containing that text which is //h2[@id='_Tabellerochdiagram']/following-sibling::ul//a[contains(.,'Finansmarknadsstatistik,')].

Answer (score 1):

This should download the excel file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.scb.se/hitta-statistik/statistik-efter-amne/finansmarknad/finansmarknadsstatistik/finansmarknadsstatistik/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//h2[@id='_Tabellerochdiagram']/..//ul//a)[1]"))).click()
```

You may use a little easier, but probably a less reliable locator startegy in lieu of the last line of above co:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "((//*[contains(text(), 'Finansmarknadsstatistik,')])[2]"))).click()
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  I figured it out earlier by using driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@id='_Tabellerochdiagram']/following::a").click() , I erroneously used -sibling next to following